# Subtract and display in Percentile

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in sql server table like the following:

```
  Slno  Revenue     Data        Loading
   1    8989898     10/07/12    Before Load
   2    2124124     10/07/12    After Load
```

I want to subtract both the values and display the result as percentage say "10%"

Please help with a correct query to compute the following

Thanks

Comment: I guess you mean subtract the revenues, but then show as a percentage of *what*?

Comment: Percentage of the revenue that is subtracted

Comment: Are they always only two rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select convert(varchar,((t.revenue - tt.revenue)*100)/(t.revenue)) +'%'   as value
from dbo.Table_1 t
inner join dbo.Table_1 tt on tt.data = t.data and t.loading = 'Before Load' and tt.loading = 'After Load'
```

this is under assumption that only one before load(and after load) exist for a single date

Comment: select t.LoadDate,t.country, convert(varchar,((t.grossrevenue - tt.grossrevenue)*100)/(t.grossrevenue)) +'%'   as Variance
from Sumamry t
inner join Summary tt 
on tt.AutoId = t.Autoid+1 
and t.Remarks = 'Before Load' 
and tt.Remarks = 'After Load'
where t.Country ='EU'
-- and t.LoadDate = '2012-07-23'


Though there are 2 records for the given date I am getting empty set on using t.Loaddate


Result

LoadDate      country Variance
2012-07-13 00:00:00 EU 0%
2012-07-23 06:50:46 EU -1%
2012-07-23 06:56:57 EU 98%
2012-07-24 01:55:44 EU 0%
2012-07-25 02:15:59 EU -1%

Comment: No this is not correct, how can you be so sure that same date field would be just next one. I am saying this because you have used "inner join Summary tt on tt.AutoId = t.Autoid+1 " and the id doesn't match the scerio then your code may break. I hope you understand my point

Comment: If you feel my answer is correct kindly help me by accepting it as the right answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
 Declare @Sample Table
 ( SNo int,
   revenue int,
   date datetime,
   Loading varchar(20)
 )

Insert into @Sample
values 
(1, 8989898,'10/07/12','Before Load'),
(2,2124124 ,'10/07/12','After Load')

 SELECT  
((cast(a.revenue as float) - cast(b.revenue as float))/cast(a.revenue as float))*100.0 AS     diff
FROM @Sample a
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Sample b
ON  b.Sno = (a.Sno +1)
```

If the datatype for revenue column is float then you need not cast it .
Edit :

```
 SELECT  
cast(((cast(f.revenue as float) - cast(f2.revenue as float))/cast(f.revenue as float))*100.0 as varchar(max))+'%'
 AS diff
FROM @Sample f
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Sample f2
ON  f2.Sno = (f.Sno +1)
```

Comment: The values are to be displayed as 10% etc...I get float values

Comment: It is showing the values as CLOB - But when I paste the clob values into notepad I get correct values